# inner while with random values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, random, while-loop

I want to create 100 random cardnumbers. I have a while for those 100 rows and an inner while for random numbers.
With this code I can create random numbers but the 100 rows have always the same number and I want a new one for each row.

```
Create Table #Nr_Cartao
(valor varchar(20) not null) 

declare @NrCartao varchar(20);
declare @NrCartao16Digitos varchar(20);
declare @counter int;
declare @random int;
declare @Nr_iterações int;
declare @digitos int;

set @Nr_iterações = 100;
set @NrCartao9Digitos = '';
set @NrCartao = '';
set @counter = 0;
set @digitos = 1

While @counter < @Nr_iterações
begin

While @digitos <= 16
Begin

set @random = rand()*10
set @NrCartao = @NrCartao + '' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @random)

if (@digitos % 4) = 0 and @digitos < 16
set @NrCartao = @NrCartao + '-'

set @digitos= @digitos +1

end;

set @NrCartao16Digitos = @NrCartao;
set @counter = @counter + 1;

insert into #Nr_Cartao values( @NrCartao16Digitos);

end

select *
from #Nr_Cartao
go;
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still intending to continue with your query, it's just missing to reset values for `@digitos` and `@NrCartao`

```
    INSERT INTO #Nr_Cartao
    VALUES (@NrCartao16Digitos); 
    SET @digitos = 1 -- reset to 1
    SET @NrCartao = '' -- to empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks very *procedural*, but with `T-SQL` one should prefer *set-based* approaches.

I do not absolutely understand what you try to achieve, but the following lines will bring you the numbers from 1 to 100 in a random sort order:

```
WITH row100 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SortId
    FROM sys.objects AS o --Should contain at least 100 rows...
)
SELECT * 
FROM row100
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

The CTE *row100* brings back 100 running numbers. Without the CTE you would get 100 rows too, but the running numbers would not stay within the range of 1 to 100. The final `SELECT` does an `ORDER BY NEWID()` which is a *quasi-random* result.